# Margins of error for a simple multiple-choice question

Tags: confidence-interval, categorical-data, survey, barplot

I wish to plot error bars on a bar chart that represents the answers of 200 respondents, randomly selected from a population of 50,000,000, to a simple multiple-choice question. Here are the proportions of answers:

Option A: 83%
Option B: 4%
Option C: 10.5%
Option D: 2.5%

At the moment I'm trying to use this formula:

$$z\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$$

This gives the following margins of error:

Option A: 6.85%
Option B: 3.57%
Option C: 5.59%
Option D: 2.85%

It's against this backdrop that I have the following three questions:

1. Am I using the right formula for this type of survey question, or should I be using a simple percentage of *p* (which is an option in Excel)?
2. Does it make any sense for a margin of error to be greater than *p*, and hence the lower limit to be less than zero, as it will be for option D?
3. Is it even worth plotting error bars when *p* is so high for option A and all I'm looking for is the most popular option?

Comment: Error bars are not good for revealing uncertainty about which is most popular since they pertain to individual choices rather than differences between choices. Although one can be calculated from the other, it is unlikely many of your readers will be able to do so.

Comment: This seems like a good, & perfectly clear, question to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

David, my thought was that if the lower limit for option A was 76.15% and the upper limit for option C was 16.09%, this would confirm that option A was most popular. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I cannot remember the reference, but I do believe that in order to use that rule, you need to make sure that *np*>10. and that *n(1-p)*>10. That being said, I arrived here in search of answers for the exact same question.